# How to check if lists have the same value in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am currently working on a grails project right now where I needed to combine the result of my query in a list. The problem is, there are instances that the result of my query returns equal values, which causes an error message: **A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session**

Here's my code:

```
List permissions = []
            cmd?.role.each{ role ->
                permissions.add(RolePermission.executeQuery("select distinct rp.permission from RolePermission rp where rp.role = ?",[Role.get(role.toLong())]))
            }
```

The object role here may contain two different role names that in some instances the permissions present in these role names are the same.

How will I modify my query in such a way that I can only get the unique values from the result ? I've tried using distinct, but it didn't work.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but from your description I think this is it.  What the below line does is iterate over your passed in roles (I assume these are role id's from the syntax) and for each role id it finds a RolePermission for the Role.  Each permission found is added as a list to permissions.  So, at the end you should have a list of RolePermissions.

Now, what I'm not understanding is the distinctness your looking for.  Are you saying that a Role can return more than one RolePermission and your trying to make sure that the returned RolePermissions are unique in the final list?  If so you could return the list as a set (i.e. return permissions as Set).  Please let me know where my understanding falls short.

```
def permissions = cmd?.role.collect{RolePermission.findByRole(Role.get(it.toLong()))}
return permissions as Set
```

Alternatively, you could use a criteria:

```
def c = RolePermission.createCriteria()
def results = c.listdistinct () {
  roles {
    'in'("id", cmd?.role as List) 
  }
}
```

I didn't run this through the compiler, but it should work.

Comment: The scenario is this: the role object there can have multiple values (ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SYSTEM_MANAGER), now the ROLE_ADMIN here may contain permissions that maybe present in ROLE_SYSTEM_MANAGER. In my permission list, I need to get the permissions of both the ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SYSTEM_MANAGER. With my existing hsql, I am getting all the permissions contained by the two role. What I wanted to do is to get ONLY the DISTINCT/UNIQUE permissions from the roles. Example, ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SYSTEM_MANAGER have READ_ANNOUNCEMENT permissions, I need to get only one instance of these permissions.

Comment: okay, then my answer stands. `return permissions as Set` will cause your list to be cast as a Set, which guarantees uniqueness.  You may need to implement Equals and Hash on RolePermissions to make sure they're being compared correctly. If your using IntelliJ or Eclipse you can autogen an Equals/Hash method that should work out of the box.  I also want to add that this isn't the only solution.  You could create a criteria for use on RolePermission and call criteria.listdistinct().  I'll post an update to my answer with the criteria solution in a minute.

Comment: thank you so much Michael..Have to consider this..ill update u later if it will work :)